# CTRL+Z makes program loop infinitely in C++

Tags: c++, loops

Ok I have a problem here. I am making a slide puzzle game. The player is asked which piece he wants to move until the puzzle is solved. If the player wants to exit before, typing `Q` or `q` and pressing `enter` will do it. The program works just fine. BUT I am having one problem: if I insert `CTRL+Z`, the program will `loop` unexpectedly...

This is the piece of code that matters:

```
        // analyzes user input
        if (piece_to_move_string == "q" ||
            piece_to_move_string == "Q")
        {
            cout << endl << "You chose to quit." << endl;
            pressanykey();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            piece_to_move = atoi(piece_to_move_string.c_str());

            if (1 <= piece_to_move && piece_to_move <= pow(puzzle_size,puzzle_size))
            {
                game_board = move_piece (game_board, piece_to_move);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Not possible.";
            }
        }
```

EDIT: but still doesn't work..

```
// analyzes user input
        if (piece_to_move_string == "q" ||
            piece_to_move_string == "Q")
        {
            cout << endl << "You chose to quit." << endl;
            pressanykey();
            break;
        }
        else if (cin.eof())
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            piece_to_move = atoi(piece_to_move_string.c_str());

            if (1 <= piece_to_move && piece_to_move <= pow(puzzle_size,puzzle_size))
            {
                game_board = move_piece (game_board, piece_to_move);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Not possible.";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Delete everything but the essentials.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> means "end of file" (assuming you're on Windows) so once the user hits that, your `cin` is in an unreadable state.  Check for `cin.eof()`:

```
if (cin.eof() || piece_to_move_string == "q" ||
                 piece_to_move_string == "Q")
{
    cout << endl << "You chose to quit." << endl;
}
```

Comment: In my experience (bash), Ctrl+D means end of file, and Ctrl+Z causes the program to run in the background.  What system is this being run on?

Comment: @Lorkenpeist: It's Ctrl+Z on Windows.  Edited accordingly.

Comment: it is being used on windows

Comment: Use a boolean test rather than specifically `eof()`. That will catch any other reasons for an unreadable state.

Comment: I don't want the program to `quit/break` when `cin.eof()`, I want it to say: `"Not possible"` and ask again for another input

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho:  Once `cin` is at End of File, you're not going to be able to ask for another input from it, since by definition it has no more data.  You can print out an error, but asking for another input seems unreasonable.